# Conversion of collection into file / Inputstream

Tags: java, file, collections, inputstream, sax

I am using a SAX parser in my code which will take either InputStream or File object only. I need to give a collection as input for this SAX parser. So i need to convert it into InputStream or File object. So can anyone tell how to convert a collection datatype into either inputstream or file.

Comment: What does your collection contain ?

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish? Collection<?>-to-XML or something completely different?

Answer (score 0):

The parser expects data in XML format. You can either code a method to lay out your collection as XML or unmarshall the collection with JAXB.

Answer (score 0):

If your Collection is like-

```
List<File> li = new ArrayList<File>();
```

then simple getter of the list you can pass to SAX method.